# c# Regex 0-9 and dash

Tags: c#, regex

I have a credit card number that I need to check if it has digits from 0 - 9 and also any dashes.

I have the following:

```
    Match match = Regex.Match(CardNumber, "[0-9-]");

    if (match.Success) 

    {

    }
```

It works but wondering if I missed anything that may not make it work.

Thanks

Comment: You should elaborate a little on your requirements, maybe. The question is pretty vague now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it only checks if there is at least one digit or dash inside the string `CardNumber`, so it would return `True` for the string `"hello0!"`.

If you want to validate the string so it *only consists of* digits and dashes, you need to use

```
Match match = Regex.Match(CardNumber, @"^[0-9-]*$");
```

Answer (score 1):

As a small note to what @Tim wrote, his regex will match `-12--34-`. Probably what you want is:

```
^([0-9]+-)*[0-9]+$
```

This will require at least a digit. If you want the empty string to match, use

```
^([0-9]+-)*[0-9]*$
```

(0 or more "groups" of one or more digits plus a `-` and a final "group" of digits)